# Save editor's value in user meta and retrieve it

Tags: user-meta, editor, wp-editor

I am making user meta fields. I have to implement a field named `business_profile` and implement editor on it. I have implemented the editor but I can't seem to either save its value or retrieve it. Below is my code.

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="address">Business Profile</label></th>
    <td><?php
        $content = get_the_author_meta('business_profile', $user->ID);
        $editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';

        wp_editor($content, $editor_id);
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And for update:

```
update_usermeta($user_id, 'business_profile', $_POST['business_profile']);
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Might be because you are using a depreciated [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_usermeta) for updating/adding the user meta (`update_usermeta`). You need to use `update_user_meta` function.

WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Comment: I changed my code to `update_usermeta($user_id, 'business_profile', $_POST['mycustomeditor']);` and it worked for me, but thankyou for your effort.

Comment: You should not use any deprecated function like `update_usermeta()` @AliZia